# Iterating through a returned list in hibernate and getting time in seconds

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a returned list of data in which i need to calculate the total seconds the device is offline. "0" is when the device is off and "1" is when it is on, which is returned in the row "ConnectedStatus". There is a "updatedtime" row also that is returned. I have to calculate the time difference between each 0 to next 1, then add them up to find total dissconn time. The Returned list will have starting Connected value as 1 and the the end connected value can either be 1 or 0, because the records are in between a time range. ConnectedStatus column values will be always like 1,0,1,0,1....

I have done like below;

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
long totalDissConnTime = 0;
for(int i = 0;i < DeviceReportList.size();i++){
    DeviceReportList reportRow = DeviceReportList.get(i);
    if(reportRow .getConnectedStatus() == 0 ){
      Date d2 = format.parse(DeviceReportList.get(i+1).getUpdatedTime());
      Date d1 = format.parse(reportRow.getUpdatedTime());
      long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
      long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
      totalDissConnTime = totalDissConnTime + diffSeconds;
      System.out.println("Loop " + (i+1) +": Device offline for "+ totalDissConnTime + " seconds.");
    }
```

I think on the line

```
Date d2 = format.parse(DeviceReportList.get(i+1).getUpdatedTime());
```

I can get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as i am doing (i+1) and if the last record have ConnectedStatus value as "0", it will not get an "(i+1)".

Please suggest a solution.
And also please suggest on making the code better. :)

Comment: Please dont downvote me, i need atleast 15 rep to be able to up vote people whom answer i find useful. And may i know the reason for downvote? so that i will not make the same mistakes again. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop must be end one element earlier:

```
for(int i = 0;i < DeviceReportList.size()-1;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't iterate until the last element:

```
for(int i = 0;i < DeviceReportList.size() - 1;i++){
```